# Passing a Variable through a curl URL

Tags: bash, macos, curl

I am having trouble running this in my bash script, hopefully someone can help me write the correct line of code:

```
#!/bin/bash

user=testadmin
pass=123456!@
cu=$(logname)

echo $cu 

curl https://cooke.jamfcloud.com/JSSResource/ldapservers/id/1/user/"$cu" --user "$user:$pass"
```

Unfortunately I get this in the terminal when I execute the script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ldap_users><size>0</size></ldap_users>
```

Any help would be appreciated, I am new and I made a previous post and some of the people in the community criticized more than helping. Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: variables will not get interpolated if they are used inside single quotes. meaning `$cu` will not expand.

Comment: And that's not how you set a variable to the output of a command.

Comment: Can someone show me an example of how I should be writing it please?

Comment: Hey I appreciate you all telling me that I did something wrong but if someone could give me an example of what I should be writing instead of just telling me I am wrong and leaving me up in the air.

Comment: The line `pass=123456!@` should cause an error because the shell will interpret `!@`. If your password really has special characters in it, single quote it: `pass='qwert!@'`.

Comment: To trouble shoot, I would echo the curl command and see what you get, and try to run that same command interactively. So, `echo curl https://cooke.jamfcloud.com/JSSResource/ldapservers/id/1/user/"$cu" --user "$user:$pass"` will show you what will really get run, and should help you figure out what's wrong.